# Unexpected values with writeUTF and readUTF in Java

Tags: java, sockets, server, dataoutputstream

I have a server listening to two different ports, after a connection is accepted, it saves the combination nameOfClient - Socket into an hashMap.
After that it starts a method in a loop to check which client is sending a message and who is the receiver of that message, it retrieves the the socket value from the hash map and use it to initialize a DataOutputStream to that socket.

The problem is that the server only receives the first two messages and they contain strange values. eg. Client 1 writeInt(1) to the server but on the other side an apparently random value is received.

The class sending data is:

```
public class Game  {
List <Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

int size;


public Game() {

(...game code here...)   
public void sendUpdatedTableValues(int nP, int nF, int nS, int sc)
{

   /* string,byte,stringa,primitivo del messaggio
   string - mittente; byte - tipo di messaggio; stringa - ricevente; prim - messaggio

   */
   try {

       DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(Lane.socket.getOutputStream());

       dataOut.writeUTF("Pista " + Lane.laneNum);
       dataOut.writeInt(1);
       dataOut.writeUTF("Amministrazione");
       dataOut.writeInt(nP);
       dataOut.writeUTF("-");
       dataOut.writeInt(nF);
       dataOut.writeUTF("-");
       dataOut.writeInt(nS);
       dataOut.writeUTF("-");
       dataOut.writeInt(sc);           
       dataOut.flush();


   } catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
 }



  /**
  * This method send the player's number of strikes
  * this method has ID byte = 3
  * @param nP - Player Number
  * @param nS - Strike Number
  */
 public void sendStrikeCounter(int nP, int nS)
{
   try {      
       DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(Lane.socket.getOutputStream());
       dataOut.writeUTF("Pista " + Lane.laneNum);
       dataOut.writeInt(3);
       dataOut.writeUTF("Amministrazione");
       dataOut.writeInt(nP);
       dataOut.writeUTF("-");
       dataOut.writeInt(nS);                     
       dataOut.flush();

   } catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
 }

 /**
* This method updates result table on server
* this method has ID byte= 4
* @param nP - Player Number
* @param nF - Frame Number
* @param res - Frame result
*/
 public void sendUpdatedResultsTable(int nP, int nF, int res)
 {
   try {      
       DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(Lane.socket.getOutputStream());
       dataOut.writeUTF("Pista " + Lane.laneNum);
       dataOut.writeInt(4);
       dataOut.writeUTF("Amministrazione");
       dataOut.writeInt(nP);
       dataOut.writeUTF("-");
       dataOut.writeInt(nF);                     
       dataOut.writeUTF("-");
       dataOut.writeInt(res);
       dataOut.flush();

   } catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
}

 /**
* This method send the player's number of spares
* this method has ID byte = 5
* @param nP - Player Number
* @param nS - Spare Number
*/
 public void sendSpareCounter(int nP, int nS)
 {
   try {      
       DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(Lane.socket.getOutputStream());
       dataOut.writeUTF("Pista " + Lane.laneNum);
       dataOut.writeInt(5);
       dataOut.writeUTF("Amministrazione");
       dataOut.writeInt(nP);
       dataOut.writeUTF("-");
       dataOut.writeInt(nS);                     
       dataOut.flush();

   } catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
}
```

The code for the server is:

```
public class Server {

public static List <Player> players = new ArrayList <Player> ();
public static HashMap <String, List<Player>> laneHashMap = new HashMap<String, List<Player>>();


ServerSocket adminListener;
ServerSocket clientListener;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Server bowling avviato:\n");

    Server server = new Server();

    /**
     * The port 9090 is reserved for the admin client, the other port is 
     * used by all the lane clients
     */
    server.adminListener = new ServerSocket(9090);
    server.clientListener = new ServerSocket(9898);

    int clientNumber = 1; //Used to keep track of every single lane

    //Create an HashMap used to store the name and the socket of the clients
    HashMap<String, Socket> socketMap = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * The server starts two different threads that keep listening for 
     * incoming connections 
     */
    new threadAdminPort(server.adminListener, socketMap).start();
    new threadClientPort(server.clientListener, socketMap, clientNumber).start();

}

/**
 * Used to listen to port 9090
 */
private static class threadAdminPort extends Thread {
    private ServerSocket adminListener;
    private HashMap<String, Socket> socketMap;

    public threadAdminPort(ServerSocket adminListener, HashMap<String, Socket> socketMap) {
        this.adminListener = adminListener;
        this.socketMap = socketMap;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                new Handler(adminListener.accept() , socketMap).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Errore di accept: " + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                adminListener.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              }
        }

    }
}

/**
 * Used to listen to port 9898
 */
private static class threadClientPort extends Thread {
    private ServerSocket clientListener;
    private HashMap<String, Socket> socketMap;
    private int clientNumber; 

    public threadClientPort(ServerSocket clientListener , HashMap<String, Socket> socketMap , int clientNumber) {
        this.clientListener = clientListener;
        this.socketMap = socketMap;
        this.clientNumber = clientNumber;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                new Handler(clientListener.accept() , socketMap , clientNumber++).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Errore di accept: " + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                clientListener.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              }
        }

    }
}


/**
 * A private thread to handle requests on a particular socket.
 */
private static class Handler extends Thread {
    Socket socket;
    HashMap<String, Socket> socketMap;
    int clientNumber;

    //Set true only if it is received a endOfGame message
    boolean endOfGame = false;

    /**
    * This constructor is meant to be used by the lane clients.
    */
    public Handler(Socket socket, HashMap<String, Socket> socketMap , int clientNumber) throws IOException {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.socketMap = socketMap;
        this.clientNumber = clientNumber;

        String clientName = "Pista " + clientNumber;

        synchronized(socketMap) {
        socketMap.put(clientName, socket);
        }

        //Send laneNum to the client
        DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dataOut.writeInt(clientNumber);

        System.out.println("- Pista " + clientNumber + " connessa -\nPronta per giocare");
    }

     /**
    * This constructor is meant to be used by the admin client as it 
    * provides no clientNumber variable.
    */
    public Handler(Socket socket , HashMap<String, Socket> socketMap) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.socketMap = socketMap;

        String clientName = "Amministrazione";

        synchronized (socketMap) {
        socketMap.put(clientName, socket);
        }

        System.out.println("- Client Amministrazione connesso -");
    }

    /**
     * This function is shared by both the admin client and the lane clients
     */

    @Override
    public void run() {

            forwardMessage();


            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              }

        if(clientNumber==0)
            System.out.println("Connessione con il client amministrazione terminata");

        else    
        System.out.println("Connessione con il client " + clientNumber + " terminata");
    }

    private void forwardMessage () {

        Set set = socketMap.entrySet();
        Iterator iterator = set.iterator();

        //The following are the fixed fields of a message
        String sender = null;
        String receiver = null;
        int messageType = 100;

        //while(iterator.hasNext()) 
        while(true){
        for(Map.Entry<String, Socket> entry : socketMap.entrySet()){
        //    Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();

            Socket tempRecSocket = (Socket) entry.getValue();
            System.out.println("Il valore di tempRecSocket è "+ tempRecSocket);
            DataInputStream dataIn;
            DataOutputStream dataOut;

            try {
                dataIn = new DataInputStream(tempRecSocket.getInputStream());

                //Analyze and understand what type of message it is and who is 
                //the sender and the receiver
                sender = dataIn.readUTF();
                messageType = dataIn.readInt();
                System.out.println("Sender ricevuto "+ sender);
                receiver = dataIn.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Receiver ricevuto " + receiver);


                switch (messageType) {
                    case 0:
                        {
                            //player 1
                            boolean start = dataIn.readBoolean();
                            String namezero = dataIn.readUTF();
                            int shoeszero = dataIn.readInt();
                            String cf = dataIn.readUTF();
                            //player 2
                            int shoesone = dataIn.readInt();
                            String nameone = dataIn.readUTF();
                            //player 3
                            int shoestwo = dataIn.readInt();
                            String nametwo = dataIn.readUTF();
                            //player 4
                            int shoesthree = dataIn.readInt();
                            String namethree = dataIn.readUTF();
                            //player 5
                            int shoesfour = dataIn.readInt();
                            String namefour = dataIn.readUTF();
                            //player 6
                            int shoesfive = dataIn.readInt();
                            String namefive = dataIn.readUTF();
                            laneHashMap.put(receiver, players); //insert in hashmap lane data
                            laneHashMap.get(receiver).add(new Player(0,namezero,shoeszero,cf)); //add player0 in players list7
                            laneHashMap.get(receiver).add(new Player(1,shoesone,nameone));
                            laneHashMap.get(receiver).add(new Player(2,shoestwo,nametwo));
                            laneHashMap.get(receiver).add(new Player(3,shoesthree,namethree));
                            laneHashMap.get(receiver).add(new Player(4,shoesfour,namefour));
                            laneHashMap.get(receiver).add(new Player(5,shoesfive,namefive));
                            Socket tempSndSocket = (Socket) socketMap.get(receiver);
                            System.out.println("Il valore di tempSndSocket è "+ tempSndSocket);
                            dataOut = new DataOutputStream(tempSndSocket.getOutputStream());
                            dataOut.writeUTF(sender);
                            dataOut.writeInt(messageType);
                            if(messageType!=0)
                                System.out.println("Valore di messageType "+ messageType);
                            dataOut.writeUTF(receiver);
                            dataOut.writeBoolean(start);
                            for (int i = 0;i<6;i++)
                            {
                                laneHashMap.get(receiver).get(i).setInitialTable();
                                dataOut.writeUTF(laneHashMap.get(receiver).get(i).getName());
                                dataOut.writeInt(0); //separatore

                            }       dataOut.flush();
                            // dataOut.close();
                            System.out.println("Il server ha inviato correttamente il messaggio di tipo 0");
                            break;
                        }
                    case 1:
                        {
                            System.out.println("Il server ha ricevuto correttamente il messaggio di tipo 1 ed ora provvederà all'invio");
                            //sendUpdatedTableValues
                            int playerNumber = dataIn.readInt();
                            dataIn.readUTF();

                            int frameNumber = dataIn.readInt();
                            dataIn.readUTF();
                            int shotNumber = dataIn.readInt();
                            dataIn.readUTF();
                            int score = dataIn.readInt();
                            System.out.println("Ho ricevuto: 1 - "+ playerNumber + "2 - framenumber "+ frameNumber+ "3 - shotNumber" + shotNumber+ "4 - score "+ score);

                            //update local player data
                            laneHashMap.get(sender).get(playerNumber).setTable(frameNumber, shotNumber, score);
                            System.out.println("In questo turno il giocatore ha totalizzato  "+ laneHashMap.get(sender).get(playerNumber).getTable(frameNumber, shotNumber));
                            Socket tempSndSocket = (Socket) socketMap.get(receiver);
                            dataOut = new DataOutputStream(tempSndSocket.getOutputStream());
                            dataOut.writeUTF(sender);
                            dataOut.writeInt(messageType);
                            dataOut.writeUTF(receiver);
                            dataOut.writeInt(playerNumber);
                            dataOut.writeUTF("-");
                            dataOut.writeInt(frameNumber);
                            dataOut.writeUTF("-");
                            dataOut.writeInt(shotNumber);
                            dataOut.writeUTF("-");
                            dataOut.writeInt(score);
                            break;
                        }

                        break;
                }
```

There's another class in the same package of Game.java that connects to the server. The game is started succesfully by another client, after that the messages cannot be correctly received.

Comment: I might miss something, but you are reading 4 Integers and 3 Strings, while you write 5 Integers and 5 Strings. Either this is not the complete code (if so, please post your full code), or that might be your problem.

Comment: You need to read string for string and int for int. If you read a string as an int you will get garbage. And you are writing a binary format, there isn't much benefit in adding text formatting. I would drop it.

Comment: As your writes are not buffered (they probably should be) doing a `flush()` doesn't do anything as there is no buffer to flush.

Comment: You're right! there was some code missing. I edited the post right now, thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually instead of full code you should be reducing this to a [MCVE] and posting that

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, your reads and writes are not symmetrical. If you call `writeInt()` there must be a corresponding `readInt()`. If you call `writeUTf()` there must be a corresponding `readUTF()`. And so on for all the other datatypes. And all these things must happen in the same order at both ends.